# How do I add to 2 lists from 1 question in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I do not know if I am going the wrong way about this, but I hope that you can help me open my eyes. I am not too sure if I worded the question correctly either but I need this to ask the user what module they would pick twice and then add it to separate lists. I am guessing there are better ways of doing this.

It is important that I insert the user-input into a list, and not a different type of container.

```
def Module_selection(lss=[]):
    print("Welcome, you can pick your module here")
    modules = ["Programming 1", "Programming 2", "Networking 1", "Mathematics"]
    print(lss)
    StudID = input("Please enter your student ID: ")
    Password = input("Please enter your password: ")
    if StudID.isnumeric():
        StudID = int(StudID)
    found = 0
    for item in lss:
        if StudID == item[5] and Password == item[4]:
            option = input("""Please select the first module you want to take
                                1)Programming 1
                                2)Programming 2
                                3)Networking 1
                                4)Mathematics""")

            found = 1

            if option == "1":
                item[6] = modules[0]
                break


            elif option == "2":
                item[6] = modules[1]
                break


            elif option == "3":
                item[6] = modules[2]
                break


            elif option == "4":
                item[6] = modules[3]
                break



    if found == 0:
        print("There is no student with this information")
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: sorry worded so badly.. been up for a very long time. Ill edit it!

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Right now the line beginning with `def` is aligned with everything else, but there should be indented lines below it, perhaps all of them?

Comment: I would recommend following a style guide like [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Thanks guys I know how to indent. Ill try and fix that but I didn't think that was how I fixed my question but thanks

Comment: You originally asked, `How do I add to 2 lists from 1 question in python` When you write code like `x = input("what is your favorite color?")` then `"what is your favorite color?"` is known as a "***prompt***" or "***user prompt***" Did you mean to ask, "How can I insert user-input into two lists without having to prompt the user twice?"

Answer (score 1):

I can tell that the most important principle in computer programming that you need to focus on is to keep different tasks as ***SEPERATE*** from each other as possible.

For example, you have:

- code which checks to see if a username and password are correct
- code which asks a student course they want to take:

  - Networking
  - English
  - Math, etc...

Checking login-credentials and choosing a course are two very ***DIFFERENT*** tasks.

However, you intertwined the code for them together.

It helps to put the code which checks the username and password in a separate function

```python
def get_and_check_login_credentials(lss=[]):
    StudID = input("Please enter your student ID: ")
    Password = input("Please enter your password: ")
    if StudID.isnumeric():
        StudID = int(StudID)
    found = 0
    for item in lss:
        if StudID == item[5] and Password == item[4]:    
            found = 1    
    if found == 0:
        print("There is no student with this information")
```

I noticed something else:

> You defined a function which contains code for both of the following:
>
> - processes many items
> - processing only one item

```python
# One function, to do it all
def Module_selection(lss=[]):
    # this function processes many items
    # `lss` contains many items
    for item in lss:
        # inside of the for-loop you have
        # a *LOT* of code for processing one item
```

The following should be written as two ***separate*** functions:
The code should not all be containing inside only one function:

1. code for processing ***many*** items
2. code for processing only ***one*** item

The following is better:

```python
def process_many(lss=[]):
    for item in lss:
        # process one item  
        process(item)  
        # almost no in-line code
        # just call the function for processing one item    

def process_one(item):
    pass
    # put code here which processes one item.
```

Below, I tried to clean up your code for checking usernames and passwords, but it makes no sense to me:

```python
def get_and_check_credentials(item):
    StudID = input("Please enter your student ID: ")
    Password = input("Please enter your password: ")
    if StudID.isnumeric():
        StudID = int(StudID)
        if StudID == item[5] and Password == item[4]:
            return True # ALLOW ACCESS
    return False # PROHIBIT ACCESS
```

Note that:

- `item[5]` contains the "***correct***" student ID.
- `item[6]` contains the "***correct***" password

I do not know why `item` is named `item`
variables names should always make sense.
For example,

- "`shirt_size`" is a better variable name than "`s`"

Why are user-name and password stored in "`item`"?

Also, imagine that you are using a website, such as `gmail.com` or `stackoverflow.com`

You type in your username.

The following is a lot like your code:

```python
StudID = input("Please enter your student ID: ")
if StudID == correct_username:
    # select a course to sign-up for
else:
    # forbid access. 
    # disallow the end-user from signing-up for college courses.
```

How  would the website know the correct student ID ahead of time?

It is as if the computer already knows what username the user is supposed to enter.

If `stackoverflow.com` were like that, then that would mean that only one person on earth could log into `stackoverflow.com` Nobody else could use `stackoverflow.com`.

I recommend that ***SEARCH*** for the student ID.

If you have a long list of student ids, you can search the list in order to see if the user-input is there.

```python
# Just as an example,
# maybe a student named "John Miller" has student id
# "8623462"
#
# "8623462", "3974923", and "2973942" are all examples
# of valid student ids
#

logins = {
  "8623462": "secret_password1234",
  "3974923": "PA$$WORD",      
  "2973942": "hE11oWoR1D"   
}

def get_and_check_credentials(logins):
    """
            +--------+--------------------------------------------+
            | OUTPUT |                  MEANING                   |
            +--------+--------------------------------------------+
            |      0 | End-user entered                           |
            |        | valid student id and password.             |
            |        | ALLOW ACCESS.                              |
            +--------+--------------------------------------------+
            |      1 | Error 1: student id is not a number        |
            +--------+--------------------------------------------+
            |      2 | Error 2: student id is not in the database |
            +--------+--------------------------------------------+
            |      3 | Error 3: username is correct, but          |
            |        | password is wrong                          |
            +--------+--------------------------------------------+

        There is only one way for things to go right
        and a millions ways for things to go wrong.   
        That is why error code 0 means everything went well.       
        
    """
    raw_id = input("Please enter your student ID: ")
    raw_password = input("Please enter your password: ")
    if raw_id.isnumeric():
        raw_id = int(raw_id)
        password = logins.get(raw_id , None)
        if password != None:
            if raw_password == password:    
                # valid username and password entered
                # allow access
                return (0, raw_id)
            else:
                # username is correct, but
                # password is wrong
                return (3, raw_password)
        else: 
            # student id is not in the database
            # student id is syntactically okay (numbers only, etc...) 
            # there is no student having the student-id `raw_id`
            return (2, raw_id)
    else: 
        # raw student id number is not numeric
        return (1, raw_id)
```

A Note:

> Generally, student id numbers are ***not*** numeric.
> The student id number `S0165139B`  contains the letters `S` and `B`
> student id numbers often contain letters, such as A, B, C, etc...
> However, you wrote your code to forbid non-numbers.
> Therefore, my code also makes sure to allow only numbers.

Another Note:

> ***ALWAYS*** call `strip()` on user-input. In python the same of the function is `strip()`, but in almost all other programming languages, the name of the function is `trim()`
> As an example, a ***trim*** function will remove space characters from the end of a phone-number.
> `"(303)-111-2222  "` becomes `"(303)-111-2222"` with no space character at the end

Yet Another Note:

> Suppose that your goal was to cook a 5-course dinner.
> Maybe one function makes only dessert  ... ice-cream, Gulab Jamun, German chocolate cake, tiramisu.... I don't know.
> A different function in your code will make the entire feast.
> The function which makes the the entire feast is called the "***main***" function.
> In your case, you named your ***main*** function "`Module_selection`"
> The name is okay, but your `main` function should *NOT* contain code.
> `main()` should be short (at most 15 lines of code)
> `main` should do almost nothing but call ***other*** functions
> If you are cooking a large feaast, `main` should call `make_dessert()` and main should call `make_side_dish()`.
> `main()` should *not* contain any of the details.
> `main()` should *not* contain any "***in-line***" code
> Your ***main*** function `Module_selection()` currently contains a million little detailed lines of code.
> I cannot seperate `making_dessert()` from `make_the_drinks()`
> Next time, ***KEEP EVERYTHING SEPERATE***
> The principle of "***modularity***" will help you write better programs in the future.

```python
def main():
    while True:
        login_result = get_and_check_login_credentials()
        if not is_valid(login_result):
            continue # go back to the start of the loop
        # otherwise...
        sign_up_for_classes(login_result.username)

def sign_up_for_classes():
    while(True):
        print_the_menu()
        user_input = get_the_menu_selection()
        if user_want_to_quit(user_input):
            return
        sign_up_for_chosen_class(user_input)
```

One Last Note:

> I have *not* fixed all of the mistakes in your code.
> However, I hope that my suggestions will give you a good start.